# What fonts are used for this "Wood Engraved Logo MockUp"?

Tags: font-identification

[image: wood logo with burnt look.]
<sup>Source: [GraphicBurger.com](http://graphicburger.com/wood-engraved-logo-mock-up/)</sup>

I'm sure a few here have seen this image before. I'm hoping someone can help identify the fonts.

Here is the un-skewed version of the logo:

[image: logo un-skewed]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hey guys :) The font for "Wood+Engraved" is indeed Alegreya Black and "Your Logo" is custom based on QumpellkaNo12 - http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/qumpellkano12

I created the logo with Illustrator and placed in Ps as vector shape.

Comment: Nothing like getting the answer from the person who made it, huh?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the raw data of the source file provided by the site you got the image from, the guts of your image are created inside a `Vector Smart Object.psb` and the rest of what you see is just effects applied to that object.

Digging through the raw data, I found something interesting which kind of baffles me. The image was constructed using a photographed image that was converted into TIFF and then heavily cleaned up and modified, suggesting no use of actual fonts to create this which is confusing giving there has to be a way to modify the "logo" if you will. Anyway, here is the raw dump of the file above that is responsible for your image which was apparently created in CS5. I will keep looking to see if I can find out the font resource used but so far seems like a no luck. You might have to browse font websites to look for something that visually seems the same in the meantime.

```
<?xpacket begin="" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.3-c011 66.145661, 2012/02/06-14:56:27        ">
   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/">
         <xmp:Rating>0</xmp:Rating>
         <xmp:ModifyDate>2013-04-08T23:48:09+03:00</xmp:ModifyDate>
         <xmp:CreateDate>2013-03-10T01:10:42</xmp:CreateDate>
         <xmp:MetadataDate>2013-04-08T23:48:09+03:00</xmp:MetadataDate>
         <xmp:CreatorTool>Adobe Photoshop CS5 Windows</xmp:CreatorTool>
      </rdf:Description>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:aux="http://ns.adobe.com/exif/1.0/aux/">
         <aux:LensInfo>6100/1000 30500/1000 0/0 0/0</aux:LensInfo>
         <aux:Lens>6.1-30.5 mm</aux:Lens>
         <aux:ApproximateFocusDistance>37/100</aux:ApproximateFocusDistance>
         <aux:FlashCompensation>0/1</aux:FlashCompensation>
         <aux:Firmware>1.00</aux:Firmware>
      </rdf:Description>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:photoshop="http://ns.adobe.com/photoshop/1.0/">
         <photoshop:DateCreated>2013-03-10T01:10:42</photoshop:DateCreated>
         <photoshop:ColorMode>3</photoshop:ColorMode>
         <photoshop:ICCProfile>sRGB IEC61966-2.1</photoshop:ICCProfile>
      </rdf:Description>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:xmpMM="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/"
            xmlns:stEvt="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/ResourceEvent#"
            xmlns:stRef="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/ResourceRef#">
         <xmpMM:DocumentID>xmp.did:FFAB149C9E89E211AFFCD6098C4EFECC</xmpMM:DocumentID>
         <xmpMM:History>
            <rdf:Seq>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stEvt:action>derived</stEvt:action>
                  <stEvt:parameters>converted from image/x-canon-cr2 to image/tiff</stEvt:parameters>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stEvt:action>saved</stEvt:action>
                  <stEvt:instanceID>xmp.iid:FFAB149C9E89E211AFFCD6098C4EFECC</stEvt:instanceID>
                  <stEvt:when>2013-03-10T18:21:49+02:00</stEvt:when>
                  <stEvt:softwareAgent>Adobe Photoshop Camera Raw 6.7 (Windows)</stEvt:softwareAgent>
                  <stEvt:changed>/</stEvt:changed>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stEvt:action>saved</stEvt:action>
                  <stEvt:instanceID>xmp.iid:1CA1A5077889E2118AA3C5E29865045B</stEvt:instanceID>
                  <stEvt:when>2013-03-10T18:22:49+02:00</stEvt:when>
                  <stEvt:softwareAgent>Adobe Photoshop CS5 Windows</stEvt:softwareAgent>
                  <stEvt:changed>/</stEvt:changed>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stEvt:action>converted</stEvt:action>
                  <stEvt:parameters>from image/tiff to application/vnd.adobe.photoshop</stEvt:parameters>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stEvt:action>derived</stEvt:action>
                  <stEvt:parameters>converted from image/tiff to application/vnd.adobe.photoshop</stEvt:parameters>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stEvt:action>saved</stEvt:action>
                  <stEvt:instanceID>xmp.iid:1DA1A5077889E2118AA3C5E29865045B</stEvt:instanceID>
                  <stEvt:when>2013-03-10T18:22:49+02:00</stEvt:when>
                  <stEvt:softwareAgent>Adobe Photoshop CS5 Windows</stEvt:softwareAgent>
                  <stEvt:changed>/</stEvt:changed>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stEvt:action>saved</stEvt:action>
                  <stEvt:instanceID>xmp.iid:1EA1A5077889E2118AA3C5E29865045B</stEvt:instanceID>
                  <stEvt:when>2013-03-10T18:23:10+02:00</stEvt:when>
                  <stEvt:softwareAgent>Adobe Photoshop CS5 Windows</stEvt:softwareAgent>
                  <stEvt:changed>/</stEvt:changed>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stEvt:action>saved</stEvt:action>
                  <stEvt:instanceID>xmp.iid:1FA1A5077889E2118AA3C5E29865045B</stEvt:instanceID>
                  <stEvt:when>2013-03-10T18:28:15+02:00</stEvt:when>
                  <stEvt:softwareAgent>Adobe Photoshop CS5 Windows</stEvt:softwareAgent>
                  <stEvt:changed>/</stEvt:changed>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stEvt:action>saved</stEvt:action>
                  <stEvt:instanceID>xmp.iid:20A1A5077889E2118AA3C5E29865045B</stEvt:instanceID>
                  <stEvt:when>2013-03-10T18:30:48+02:00</stEvt:when>
                  <stEvt:softwareAgent>Adobe Photoshop CS5 Windows</stEvt:softwareAgent>
                  <stEvt:changed>/</stEvt:changed>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stEvt:action>saved</stEvt:action>
                  <stEvt:instanceID>xmp.iid:21A1A5077889E2118AA3C5E29865045B</stEvt:instanceID>
                  <stEvt:when>2013-03-10T18:31:29+02:00</stEvt:when>
                  <stEvt:softwareAgent>Adobe Photoshop CS5 Windows</stEvt:softwareAgent>
                  <stEvt:changed>/</stEvt:changed>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stEvt:action>saved</stEvt:action>
                  <stEvt:instanceID>xmp.iid:22A1A5077889E2118AA3C5E29865045B</stEvt:instanceID>
                  <stEvt:when>2013-03-10T18:32:47+02:00</stEvt:when>
                  <stEvt:softwareAgent>Adobe Photoshop CS5 Windows</stEvt:softwareAgent>
                  <stEvt:changed>/</stEvt:changed>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stEvt:action>saved</stEvt:action>
                  <stEvt:instanceID>xmp.iid:23A1A5077889E2118AA3C5E29865045B</stEvt:instanceID>
                  <stEvt:when>2013-03-10T18:34:09+02:00</stEvt:when>
                  <stEvt:softwareAgent>Adobe Photoshop CS5 Windows</stEvt:softwareAgent>
                  <stEvt:changed>/</stEvt:changed>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stEvt:action>saved</stEvt:action>
                  <stEvt:instanceID>xmp.iid:61F8397EA089E2118AA3C5E29865045B</stEvt:instanceID>
                  <stEvt:when>2013-03-10T18:35:18+02:00</stEvt:when>
                  <stEvt:softwareAgent>Adobe Photoshop CS5 Windows</stEvt:softwareAgent>
                  <stEvt:changed>/</stEvt:changed>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stEvt:action>saved</stEvt:action>
                  <stEvt:instanceID>xmp.iid:55C35193A489E2118AA3C5E29865045B</stEvt:instanceID>
                  <stEvt:when>2013-03-10T19:34:01+02:00</stEvt:when>
                  <stEvt:softwareAgent>Adobe Photoshop CS5 Windows</stEvt:softwareAgent>
                  <stEvt:changed>/</stEvt:changed>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stEvt:action>saved</stEvt:action>
                  <stEvt:instanceID>xmp.iid:56C35193A489E2118AA3C5E29865045B</stEvt:instanceID>
                  <stEvt:when>2013-03-10T19:34:26+02:00</stEvt:when>
                  <stEvt:softwareAgent>Adobe Photoshop CS5 Windows</stEvt:softwareAgent>
                  <stEvt:changed>/</stEvt:changed>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stEvt:action>saved</stEvt:action>
                  <stEvt:instanceID>xmp.iid:EC599B78258AE21184A4A1A07AF25C11</stEvt:instanceID>
                  <stEvt:when>2013-03-11T10:28:01+02:00</stEvt:when>
                  <stEvt:softwareAgent>Adobe Photoshop CS5 Windows</stEvt:softwareAgent>
                  <stEvt:changed>/</stEvt:changed>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stEvt:action>saved</stEvt:action>
                  <stEvt:instanceID>xmp.iid:ED599B78258AE21184A4A1A07AF25C11</stEvt:instanceID>
                  <stEvt:when>2013-03-11T10:29:40+02:00</stEvt:when>
                  <stEvt:softwareAgent>Adobe Photoshop CS5 Windows</stEvt:softwareAgent>
                  <stEvt:changed>/</stEvt:changed>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stEvt:action>saved</stEvt:action>
                  <stEvt:instanceID>xmp.iid:EE599B78258AE21184A4A1A07AF25C11</stEvt:instanceID>
                  <stEvt:when>2013-03-11T10:30:02+02:00</stEvt:when>
                  <stEvt:softwareAgent>Adobe Photoshop CS5 Windows</stEvt:softwareAgent>
                  <stEvt:changed>/</stEvt:changed>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stEvt:action>saved</stEvt:action>
                  <stEvt:instanceID>xmp.iid:EF599B78258AE21184A4A1A07AF25C11</stEvt:instanceID>
                  <stEvt:when>2013-03-11T10:33:25+02:00</stEvt:when>
                  <stEvt:softwareAgent>Adobe Photoshop CS5 Windows</stEvt:softwareAgent>
                  <stEvt:changed>/</stEvt:changed>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stEvt:action>saved</stEvt:action>
                  <stEvt:instanceID>xmp.iid:F1599B78258AE21184A4A1A07AF25C11</stEvt:instanceID>
                  <stEvt:when>2013-03-11T10:35:04+02:00</stEvt:when>
                  <stEvt:softwareAgent>Adobe Photoshop CS5 Windows</stEvt:softwareAgent>
                  <stEvt:changed>/</stEvt:changed>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stEvt:action>saved</stEvt:action>
                  <stEvt:instanceID>xmp.iid:F2599B78258AE21184A4A1A07AF25C11</stEvt:instanceID>
                  <stEvt:when>2013-03-11T10:35:48+02:00</stEvt:when>
                  <stEvt:softwareAgent>Adobe Photoshop CS5 Windows</stEvt:softwareAgent>
                  <stEvt:changed>/</stEvt:changed>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stEvt:action>saved</stEvt:action>
                  <stEvt:instanceID>xmp.iid:F3599B78258AE21184A4A1A07AF25C11</stEvt:instanceID>
                  <stEvt:when>2013-03-11T10:38:04+02:00</stEvt:when>
                  <stEvt:softwareAgent>Adobe Photoshop CS5 Windows</stEvt:softwareAgent>
                  <stEvt:changed>/</stEvt:changed>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stEvt:action>saved</stEvt:action>
                  <stEvt:instanceID>xmp.iid:F4599B78258AE21184A4A1A07AF25C11</stEvt:instanceID>
                  <stEvt:when>2013-03-11T10:39:19+02:00</stEvt:when>
                  <stEvt:softwareAgent>Adobe Photoshop CS5 Windows</stEvt:softwareAgent>
                  <stEvt:changed>/</stEvt:changed>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stEvt:action>saved</stEvt:action>
                  <stEvt:instanceID>xmp.iid:941F8F396FA0E211A9B3DDD6A3E5720F</stEvt:instanceID>
                  <stEvt:when>2013-04-08T20:26:53+03:00</stEvt:when>
                  <stEvt:softwareAgent>Adobe Photoshop CS5 Windows</stEvt:softwareAgent>
                  <stEvt:changed>/</stEvt:changed>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stEvt:action>saved</stEvt:action>
                  <stEvt:instanceID>xmp.iid:981F8F396FA0E211A9B3DDD6A3E5720F</stEvt:instanceID>
                  <stEvt:when>2013-04-08T20:38:03+03:00</stEvt:when>
                  <stEvt:softwareAgent>Adobe Photoshop CS5 Windows</stEvt:softwareAgent>
                  <stEvt:changed>/</stEvt:changed>
               </rdf:li>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <stEvt:action>saved</stEvt:action>
                  <stEvt:instanceID>xmp.iid:86BD82FA87A0E211A9B3DDD6A3E5720F</stEvt:instanceID>
                  <stEvt:when>2013-04-08T23:48:09+03:00</stEvt:when>
                  <stEvt:softwareAgent>Adobe Photoshop CS5 Windows</stEvt:softwareAgent>
                  <stEvt:changed>/</stEvt:changed>
               </rdf:li>
            </rdf:Seq>
         </xmpMM:History>
         <xmpMM:OriginalDocumentID>D8B2BAB285707B47DBE8C17B2D9AD1B5</xmpMM:OriginalDocumentID>
         <xmpMM:DerivedFrom rdf:parseType="Resource">
            <stRef:instanceID>xmp.iid:1CA1A5077889E2118AA3C5E29865045B</stRef:instanceID>
            <stRef:documentID>xmp.did:FFAB149C9E89E211AFFCD6098C4EFECC</stRef:documentID>
            <stRef:originalDocumentID>D8B2BAB285707B47DBE8C17B2D9AD1B5</stRef:originalDocumentID>
         </xmpMM:DerivedFrom>
         <xmpMM:InstanceID>xmp.iid:86BD82FA87A0E211A9B3DDD6A3E5720F</xmpMM:InstanceID>
      </rdf:Description>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
         <dc:format>application/vnd.adobe.photoshop</dc:format>
      </rdf:Description>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:crs="http://ns.adobe.com/camera-raw-settings/1.0/">
         <crs:RawFileName>Picture 006.CR2</crs:RawFileName>
         <crs:Version>6.7</crs:Version>
         <crs:ProcessVersion>5.7</crs:ProcessVersion>
         <crs:WhiteBalance>Custom</crs:WhiteBalance>
         <crs:Temperature>4800</crs:Temperature>
         <crs:Tint>+42</crs:Tint>
         <crs:Exposure>+0.50</crs:Exposure>
         <crs:Shadows>5</crs:Shadows>
         <crs:Brightness>+50</crs:Brightness>
         <crs:Contrast>+25</crs:Contrast>
         <crs:Saturation>0</crs:Saturation>
         <crs:Sharpness>25</crs:Sharpness>
         <crs:LuminanceSmoothing>17</crs:LuminanceSmoothing>
         <crs:ColorNoiseReduction>51</crs:ColorNoiseReduction>
         <crs:VignetteAmount>0</crs:VignetteAmount>
         <crs:ShadowTint>0</crs:ShadowTint>
         <crs:RedHue>0</crs:RedHue>
         <crs:RedSaturation>0</crs:RedSaturation>
         <crs:GreenHue>0</crs:GreenHue>
         <crs:GreenSaturation>0</crs:GreenSaturation>
         <crs:BlueHue>0</crs:BlueHue>
         <crs:BlueSaturation>0</crs:BlueSaturation>
         <crs:FillLight>27</crs:FillLight>
         <crs:Vibrance>-11</crs:Vibrance>
         <crs:HighlightRecovery>0</crs:HighlightRecovery>
         <crs:Clarity>+100</crs:Clarity>
         <crs:Defringe>0</crs:Defringe>
         <crs:HueAdjustmentRed>0</crs:HueAdjustmentRed>
         <crs:HueAdjustmentOrange>0</crs:HueAdjustmentOrange>
         <crs:HueAdjustmentYellow>0</crs:HueAdjustmentYellow>
         <crs:HueAdjustmentGreen>0</crs:HueAdjustmentGreen>
         <crs:HueAdjustmentAqua>0</crs:HueAdjustmentAqua>
         <crs:HueAdjustmentBlue>0</crs:HueAdjustmentBlue>
         <crs:HueAdjustmentPurple>0</crs:HueAdjustmentPurple>
         <crs:HueAdjustmentMagenta>0</crs:HueAdjustmentMagenta>
         <crs:SaturationAdjustmentRed>0</crs:SaturationAdjustmentRed>
         <crs:SaturationAdjustmentOrange>0</crs:SaturationAdjustmentOrange>
         <crs:SaturationAdjustmentYellow>0</crs:SaturationAdjustmentYellow>
         <crs:SaturationAdjustmentGreen>0</crs:SaturationAdjustmentGreen>
         <crs:SaturationAdjustmentAqua>0</crs:SaturationAdjustmentAqua>
         <crs:SaturationAdjustmentBlue>0</crs:SaturationAdjustmentBlue>
         <crs:SaturationAdjustmentPurple>0</crs:SaturationAdjustmentPurple>
         <crs:SaturationAdjustmentMagenta>0</crs:SaturationAdjustmentMagenta>
         <crs:LuminanceAdjustmentRed>0</crs:LuminanceAdjustmentRed>
         <crs:LuminanceAdjustmentOrange>0</crs:LuminanceAdjustmentOrange>
         <crs:LuminanceAdjustmentYellow>0</crs:LuminanceAdjustmentYellow>
         <crs:LuminanceAdjustmentGreen>0</crs:LuminanceAdjustmentGreen>
         <crs:LuminanceAdjustmentAqua>0</crs:LuminanceAdjustmentAqua>
         <crs:LuminanceAdjustmentBlue>0</crs:LuminanceAdjustmentBlue>
         <crs:LuminanceAdjustmentPurple>0</crs:LuminanceAdjustmentPurple>
         <crs:LuminanceAdjustmentMagenta>0</crs:LuminanceAdjustmentMagenta>
         <crs:SplitToningShadowHue>0</crs:SplitToningShadowHue>
         <crs:SplitToningShadowSaturation>0</crs:SplitToningShadowSaturation>
         <crs:SplitToningHighlightHue>0</crs:SplitToningHighlightHue>
         <crs:SplitToningHighlightSaturation>0</crs:SplitToningHighlightSaturation>
         <crs:SplitToningBalance>0</crs:SplitToningBalance>
         <crs:ParametricShadows>0</crs:ParametricShadows>
         <crs:ParametricDarks>0</crs:ParametricDarks>
         <crs:ParametricLights>0</crs:ParametricLights>
         <crs:ParametricHighlights>0</crs:ParametricHighlights>
         <crs:ParametricShadowSplit>25</crs:ParametricShadowSplit>
         <crs:ParametricMidtoneSplit>50</crs:ParametricMidtoneSplit>
         <crs:ParametricHighlightSplit>75</crs:ParametricHighlightSplit>
         <crs:SharpenRadius>+1.0</crs:SharpenRadius>
         <crs:SharpenDetail>25</crs:SharpenDetail>
         <crs:SharpenEdgeMasking>0</crs:SharpenEdgeMasking>
         <crs:PostCropVignetteAmount>0</crs:PostCropVignetteAmount>
         <crs:GrainAmount>0</crs:GrainAmount>
         <crs:LuminanceNoiseReductionDetail>65</crs:LuminanceNoiseReductionDetail>
         <crs:ColorNoiseReductionDetail>50</crs:ColorNoiseReductionDetail>
         <crs:LuminanceNoiseReductionContrast>0</crs:LuminanceNoiseReductionContrast>
         <crs:LensProfileEnable>0</crs:LensProfileEnable>
         <crs:LensManualDistortionAmount>0</crs:LensManualDistortionAmount>
         <crs:PerspectiveVertical>0</crs:PerspectiveVertical>
         <crs:PerspectiveHorizontal>0</crs:PerspectiveHorizontal>
         <crs:PerspectiveRotate>0.0</crs:PerspectiveRotate>
         <crs:PerspectiveScale>100</crs:PerspectiveScale>
         <crs:AutoLateralCA>0</crs:AutoLateralCA>
         <crs:Exposure2012>0.00</crs:Exposure2012>
         <crs:Contrast2012>0</crs:Contrast2012>
         <crs:Highlights2012>0</crs:Highlights2012>
         <crs:Shadows2012>0</crs:Shadows2012>
         <crs:Whites2012>0</crs:Whites2012>
         <crs:Blacks2012>0</crs:Blacks2012>
         <crs:Clarity2012>0</crs:Clarity2012>
         <crs:ConvertToGrayscale>False</crs:ConvertToGrayscale>
         <crs:ToneCurveName>Medium Contrast</crs:ToneCurveName>
         <crs:ToneCurve>
            <rdf:Seq>
               <rdf:li>0, 0</rdf:li>
               <rdf:li>32, 22</rdf:li>
               <rdf:li>64, 56</rdf:li>
               <rdf:li>128, 128</rdf:li>
               <rdf:li>192, 196</rdf:li>
               <rdf:li>255, 255</rdf:li>
            </rdf:Seq>
         </crs:ToneCurve>
         <crs:ToneCurveRed>
            <rdf:Seq>
               <rdf:li>0, 0</rdf:li>
               <rdf:li>255, 255</rdf:li>
            </rdf:Seq>
         </crs:ToneCurveRed>
         <crs:ToneCurveGreen>
            <rdf:Seq>
               <rdf:li>0, 0</rdf:li>
               <rdf:li>255, 255</rdf:li>
            </rdf:Seq>
         </crs:ToneCurveGreen>
         <crs:ToneCurveBlue>
            <rdf:Seq>
               <rdf:li>0, 0</rdf:li>
               <rdf:li>255, 255</rdf:li>
            </rdf:Seq>
         </crs:ToneCurveBlue>
         <crs:ToneCurveName2012>Linear</crs:ToneCurveName2012>
         <crs:ToneCurvePV2012>
            <rdf:Seq>
               <rdf:li>0, 0</rdf:li>
               <rdf:li>255, 255</rdf:li>
            </rdf:Seq>
         </crs:ToneCurvePV2012>
         <crs:ToneCurvePV2012Red>
            <rdf:Seq>
               <rdf:li>0, 0</rdf:li>
               <rdf:li>255, 255</rdf:li>
            </rdf:Seq>
         </crs:ToneCurvePV2012Red>
         <crs:ToneCurvePV2012Green>
            <rdf:Seq>
               <rdf:li>0, 0</rdf:li>
               <rdf:li>255, 255</rdf:li>
            </rdf:Seq>
         </crs:ToneCurvePV2012Green>
         <crs:ToneCurvePV2012Blue>
            <rdf:Seq>
               <rdf:li>0, 0</rdf:li>
               <rdf:li>255, 255</rdf:li>
            </rdf:Seq>
         </crs:ToneCurvePV2012Blue>
         <crs:CameraProfile>Adobe Standard</crs:CameraProfile>
         <crs:CameraProfileDigest>42A4461E39D1D90C00E0325F36659314</crs:CameraProfileDigest>
         <crs:LensProfileSetup>LensDefaults</crs:LensProfileSetup>
         <crs:HasSettings>True</crs:HasSettings>
         <crs:HasCrop>False</crs:HasCrop>
         <crs:AlreadyApplied>True</crs:AlreadyApplied>
      </rdf:Description>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:tiff="http://ns.adobe.com/tiff/1.0/">
         <tiff:Orientation>1</tiff:Orientation>
         <tiff:XResolution>2400000/10000</tiff:XResolution>
         <tiff:YResolution>2400000/10000</tiff:YResolution>
         <tiff:ResolutionUnit>2</tiff:ResolutionUnit>
         <tiff:Make>Canon</tiff:Make>
         <tiff:Model>Canon PowerShot G12</tiff:Model>
      </rdf:Description>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:exif="http://ns.adobe.com/exif/1.0/">
         <exif:ExifVersion>0230</exif:ExifVersion>
         <exif:ColorSpace>1</exif:ColorSpace>
         <exif:PixelXDimension>1497</exif:PixelXDimension>
         <exif:PixelYDimension>943</exif:PixelYDimension>
         <exif:DateTimeOriginal>2013-03-10T01:10:42</exif:DateTimeOriginal>
         <exif:ExposureTime>25/10</exif:ExposureTime>
         <exif:FNumber>8/1</exif:FNumber>
         <exif:ISOSpeedRatings>
            <rdf:Seq>
               <rdf:li>80</rdf:li>
            </rdf:Seq>
         </exif:ISOSpeedRatings>
         <exif:ShutterSpeedValue>-1321928/1000000</exif:ShutterSpeedValue>
         <exif:ApertureValue>6000000/1000000</exif:ApertureValue>
         <exif:ExposureBiasValue>0/3</exif:ExposureBiasValue>
         <exif:MaxApertureValue>107/32</exif:MaxApertureValue>
         <exif:SubjectDistance>37/100</exif:SubjectDistance>
         <exif:MeteringMode>5</exif:MeteringMode>
         <exif:Flash rdf:parseType="Resource">
            <exif:Fired>False</exif:Fired>
            <exif:Return>0</exif:Return>
            <exif:Mode>2</exif:Mode>
            <exif:Function>False</exif:Function>
            <exif:RedEyeMode>False</exif:RedEyeMode>
         </exif:Flash>
         <exif:FocalLength>8108/1000</exif:FocalLength>
         <exif:FocalPlaneXResolution>3648000/292</exif:FocalPlaneXResolution>
         <exif:FocalPlaneYResolution>2736000/219</exif:FocalPlaneYResolution>
         <exif:FocalPlaneResolutionUnit>2</exif:FocalPlaneResolutionUnit>
         <exif:SensingMethod>2</exif:SensingMethod>
         <exif:FileSource>3</exif:FileSource>
         <exif:CustomRendered>0</exif:CustomRendered>
         <exif:ExposureMode>1</exif:ExposureMode>
         <exif:WhiteBalance>0</exif:WhiteBalance>
         <exif:DigitalZoomRatio>3648/3648</exif:DigitalZoomRatio>
         <exif:SceneCaptureType>0</exif:SceneCaptureType>
         <exif:LensInfo>
            <rdf:Seq>
               <rdf:li>6100/1000</rdf:li>
            </rdf:Seq>
         </exif:LensInfo>
         <exif:Lens>6.1-30.5 mm</exif:Lens>
         <exif:SensitivityType>4</exif:SensitivityType>
      </rdf:Description>
   </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>





















<?xpacket end="w"?>
```

[image]

Comment: Whoa, that's quite in-depth. The closest font I found for "Wood + Engraved" is "Alegreya ht Pro Black" but like you said I think the "Your Logo" font is custom.

Comment: @deecemobile, yeah I don't do anything half-a**ed - only got one mode :) Jokes aside, I did a graphic analysis on it too and found that no font completely comes close to it, several have individual elements but no one single one has all of it. Leads me to believe it is indeed customized. Also, I played around with the PSD to find out that pretty much any image (texts work better) you put in the PSB file, it will render it with the inset wood graved style above using tons of effects.

Comment: Ya I know how that file works. It's from graphicriver.net I think. Anything you place in that Smart Object gets the effect applied to it. Must just be a custom example.

Comment: Yeap, and I am posting a sample that I think looks cool :)